# Where is the Case compact layout used?

Tags: salesforce1-app, compact-layout

In the Salesforce.com release notes on Compact Page Layouts ([here](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/winter14/release-notes/compact_layout_overview.htm)), it says:

"In Salesforce1, compact layouts determine the fields that show up in:

- An object’s record highlights area
- An object’s record preview cards (but not those shown in search
  results)
- Enhanced lookup cards on a record’s related information page"

I would like to know what is meant by "an object's record highlights area" I would like to see a screenshot of this in action.

I would also like to know in what context, e.g., when and where, the object's record preview card is displayed.

Reason for my question: I have created a compact page layout for the Case object and assigned it the a specific record type however I am not able to see where this compact layout is used within Salesforce1.

Comment: It's used in the Service Cloud Console.

Comment: ?? how is that? Surely the service cloud console isn't used in Salesforce1 mobile...

Comment: Ok, reading this now.  This should be available.  Have you assigned the compact layout to a user profile?

Comment: yes, then logged in to SF1 using that profile but can't see anywhere where the compact layout is used.